# How does getCurrentSession work without openSession?

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

This is my code:

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"/>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>

        <mapping class="biz.tugay.saqila.model.Actor" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
package biz.tugay.saqila.dao;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 06/08/15 Time: 18:29 */

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory SESSION_FACTORY;

    public static void buildSessionFactory() {
        if (SESSION_FACTORY != null) {
            return;
        }

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        SESSION_FACTORY = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    }

    public static Session getCurrentSession() {
        return SESSION_FACTORY.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public static void killSessionFactory() {
        if (SESSION_FACTORY != null) {
            SESSION_FACTORY.close();
        }
    }

}
```

and a sample DAO class:

```
package biz.tugay.saqila.dao;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 06/08/15 Time: 18:37 */

import biz.tugay.saqila.model.Actor;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ActorDao {

    public List<Actor> getAllActors() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Actor> actors = session.createQuery("FROM Actor").list();
        session.close();
        return actors;
    }

    public Actor getWithId(int id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Actor actor = (Actor) session.get(Actor.class, id);
        session.close();
        return actor;
    }

}
```

Well as you can see I am not calling **openSession** anywhere, just **getCurrentSession**. But how does this work?

Also, is this the right way to do things or am I just lucky that this works?

Btw I also have this listener:

```
package biz.tugay.saqila.servlet;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 06/08/15 Time: 19:00 */


import biz.tugay.saqila.dao.HibernateUtil;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class HibernateConfigurator implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        System.out.println("Killing Session Factory.");
        HibernateUtil.killSessionFactory();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getCurrentSession%28%29) says:

> Obtains the current session. The definition of what exactly "current" means controlled by the CurrentSessionContext impl configured for use.

You're using a ThreadLocalSessionContext. [Its javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/internal/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html) says:

> A CurrentSessionContext impl which scopes the notion of current session by the current thread of execution. [...] In the interest of usability, it was decided to have this default impl actually generate a session upon first request and then clean it up after the Transaction associated with that session is committed/rolled-back.

You shouldn't close sessions obtained that way. Instead, you should commit the transaction that you have begun. This will close the session, as the documentation says.

Comment: So this is the right way to do it?         Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        List<Actor> actors = session.createQuery("FROM Actor").list();
        transaction.commit();
        return actors;

Comment: Better, but still doesn't deal with exceptions properly. The proper idiom is explained in the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged. But I would really try to use a framework allowing declarative transaction management if I were you: EJBs or Spring. That would allow you to avoid writing all this boilerplate code.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `hibernate.current_session_context_class` to thread, then you can access that session anywhere in application by using the `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

if you don't want the session to be bound to context then use OpenSession . In some scenario you may need a different session - other than one bound to the context in that case you can use OpenSession instead of currentSession.

`SessionFactory.openSession()` always opens a new session that you have to close once you are done with the DB operations. `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` returns a session bound to a context and you don't need to close this.

**You should never use one session per application** - session is **not a thread safe** object,Which cannot be shared by multiple threads.Always use **one session per transaction**

Comment: You should never use one session per application - session is not a thread safe object -> So you mean I should use openSession?

Comment: *7 years of cricket noises*